# Google search API searchType = image

Tags: image, api, google-image-search

Google search API, as of this morning ( 7/30/2020 ) the Google API custom search with searchtype = image returns without the items[] array. I verified my CSE setting that includes image search = enabled and search the whole web;  As nothing changed on my side and it all worked for several years until this morning i'm trying to find what has changed / happen;
The type of search I'm executing is like below:

for example:
"request": [
{
"title": "Google Custom Search - ocean",
"totalResults": "360000",
"searchTerms": "ocean",
"count": 10,
"startIndex": 1,
"inputEncoding": "utf8",
"outputEncoding": "utf8",
"safe": "off",
"cx": "XXX My Own Instance xxx",
"searchType": "image",
"imgSize": "xxlarge"
}
It returns all metadata with number of results and search time etc. but no items, so the my usual query that worked up to now, can't use the fields = kind,items(title,link,snippet)  parameter ..

Answer (score 0):

Now 8 hours later I tried again to execute a query with 'searchType=image" and it works;
From my Angular application as well as Python script and the REST testing tools.
I'm guessing Google had some downtime or server malfunction and then they fixed it.

Appreciate if anyone has confirmation of the scenario I'm suspecting